# SQL Server query filling null value with next row value which is not empty

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server query like this:

```
select 
    CONVERT(datetime,tglolah,103) as dates,
    pks,asal,
    tandan,tbs_diolah,cpo,pko,
    CAST(NULLIF(cpo,0) as float)  / (NULLIF(tbs_diolah, 0)) as rend_ms,
from 
    daily_guu
where 
    year(CONVERT(datetime,tglolah, 103)) = 2017
    and month(CONVERT(datetime, tglolah, 103)) = 1
    and pks = 11
```

and the result like in this table

```
|   Dates  | PKS | Asal | Tandan | tbs_diolah |  cpo  |  pko | Rend_ms
|:---------|-----|------|--------|------------|------ |------|--------
| 2017-1-1 | 11  | 58   |    0   |     0      |  0    |   0  | null
| 2017-1-2 | 11  | 58   | 100460 |     0      |  0    |   0  | null
| 2017-1-3 | 11  | 58   | 136100 |     0      |  0    |   0  | null      
| 2017-1-16| 11  | 18   | 179330 |     0      |  0    |   0  | null
| 2017-1-16| 11  | 19   | 279990 |  293820    | 69633 |12933 | 0.236
| 2017-1-20| 11  | 40   | 298530 |  563390    |125805 |25973 | 0.223
```

If `tandan` column is not zero or null but `tbs_diolah` and `cpo` are null or zero, how can I fill `rend_ms` value with the nearest next value which has value?

In the table I want the `rend_ms` value for date 2,3 and 16 january to be filled with the value from 16 january which is 0.236. I am lacking experience in SQL Server. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please, post your table schema.

Comment: Use the Lead function: https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/11/15/sql-server-introduction-to-lead-and-lag-analytic-functions-introduced-in-sql-server-2012/

Comment: Consider it this way: you now need to write a query which specifically finds the null row with Asal=18. How do you think you would do that? Also, you must have columns to order on. For example, is the null row the previous row because Asal = 18 (which is smaller than 19). Please add an `order by` to your original query to illustrate this.

Comment: in lead function we have to determine how many row to skip to in order to find nearest row that have value. but i dont know how to figure it out